# How to play youtube from rss on UWP

Tags: c#, wordpress, uwp, rss

I'm using an appstudio code and when I get the post from my wordpress I can view pictures and text and everything fine but when I try to play the youtube video It's open Microsoft edge to show me the video
Can anyone help me 
Here's the Html Block code

```
                        <was_controls:HtmlBlock
                        Grid.Row="2"
                        FlowDirection="RightToLeft"
                        Margin="24,10,24,130"
                        Style="{StaticResource HtmlPersonalStyle}"
                        FontSize="{Binding ViewModel.FontSize, ElementName=root}"
                        Source="{Binding ViewModel.SelectedItem.Description}" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
```

and the Html Style:

```
    <Style TargetType="was:HtmlBlock" x:Key="HtmlPersonalStyle">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ApplicationHeaderForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="DocumentStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <was:DocumentStyle>
                <was:DocumentStyle.Channel9>
                    <was:ImageStyle HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </was:DocumentStyle.Channel9>
                <was:DocumentStyle.Img>
                    <was:ImageStyle HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </was:DocumentStyle.Img>
                <was:DocumentStyle.P>
                    <was:ParagraphStyle Margin="0,24,0,24"  />
                </was:DocumentStyle.P>

                <was:DocumentStyle.Code>
                    <was:TextStyle Foreground="{StaticResource NavigationPaneButton}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                </was:DocumentStyle.Code>
                <was:DocumentStyle.FigCaption>
                    <was:ParagraphStyle Foreground="SaddleBrown"/>
                </was:DocumentStyle.FigCaption>
                <was:DocumentStyle.Ul>
                    <was:ContainerStyle Margin="0,24,0,24" />
                </was:DocumentStyle.Ul>
                <was:DocumentStyle.H1>
                    <was:ParagraphStyle FontSizeRatio="2" />
                </was:DocumentStyle.H1>
                <was:DocumentStyle.H2>
                    <was:ParagraphStyle />
                </was:DocumentStyle.H2>
                <was:DocumentStyle.Li>
                    <was:ListStyle FontWeight="Bold" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                </was:DocumentStyle.Li>
                <was:DocumentStyle.Span>
                    <was:TextStyle Foreground="#FF104F83" FontStyle="Normal"/>
                </was:DocumentStyle.Span>
                <was:DocumentStyle.A>
                    <was:TextStyle Foreground="{StaticResource NavigationPaneButton}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                </was:DocumentStyle.A>
                <was:DocumentStyle.Cite>
                    <was:TextStyle Foreground="{StaticResource NavigationPaneButton}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                </was:DocumentStyle.Cite>
                <was:DocumentStyle.YouTube>
                    <was:ImageStyle HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </was:DocumentStyle.YouTube>
                <was:DocumentStyle.Figure>
                    <was:ContainerStyle Margin="0,24,0,24"/>
                </was:DocumentStyle.Figure>
                <was:DocumentStyle.Time>
                    <was:TextStyle FontSizeRatio="0.9" FontStyle="Italic" />
                </was:DocumentStyle.Time>
            </was:DocumentStyle>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: How are you developing your application? Are you using Visual Studio .NET? Do you use C# + XAML? If you get the HTML of a feed, you can display the contents using the WebView control. If you need a custom view, you should parse the contents and show each element (text, images) for yourself. This includes showing YouTube content.

Comment: I'm using c# + xaml language

Comment: @SuperJMN can you give me an example for the webview control...

Comment: @louay `HtmlBlock` from AppStudio will convert HTML to XAML. Youtube can't be streamed in `MediaPlayerElement`. So you have to create own Youtube player.

Comment: @VijayNirmal how to get the html from my local after appstudio save it !

Comment: @louay Use `HttpClient` by `HtmlAgilityPack`

Comment: @louay Any updates? Did you solve your problem?

Comment: @VijayNirmal I couldn't solve it do you have any other ideas :/

Comment: @louay You want guidance to create your own Youtube player. Am I right?

Comment: @VijayNirmal in my layout I load the content from the local folder and I don't know if there's a youtube video on it or not ...

Comment: @louay Why don't you search for `https://www.youtube.com/` in your local file? you can use [`String.Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx) to check.

Comment: @VijayNirmal that's a good idea but i have to set the viewer on the same youtube place on blog :/

Comment: @louay So you want to play the video in `HtmlBlock`? If yes then I think you can re-template `HtmlBlock` to achieve your effect. Also, take a look at [UWP-YouTube-Player](https://github.com/Vijay-Nirmal/UWP-YouTube-Player). It will help you to build your own YouTube player

Comment: @VijayNirmal that's what I'm trying to do , I'll take a look I'll replay for you thanks!

Comment: @VijayNirmal I couldn't find anyway to re-template the html block all that i can find is changing the style like text color or hover button color and image position on the template !

Comment: @louay You are right, we can't re-template it but we can add new style in [Styles](https://github.com/wasteam/waslibs/tree/master/src/AppStudio.Uwp/Controls/HtmlBlock/Styles) and edit [IFrameVideoWriter](https://github.com/wasteam/waslibs/blob/master/src/AppStudio.Uwp/Controls/HtmlBlock/Writers/IFrameVideoWriter.cs) and [YouTubeWriter.cs](https://github.com/wasteam/waslibs/blob/master/src/AppStudio.Uwp/Controls/HtmlBlock/Writers/YouTubeWriter.cs) to accomodate the new style.

Comment: @VijayNirmal how to add the changes to the html block

Comment: @louay Don't use the NuGet package. Download the `HtmlBlock` code and add it to your project manually.

Comment: @VijayNirmal thanks I'll try this and replay for you !

Comment: @VijayNirmal I found the code for open the youtube on the Html but I don't know how to open it in the same view can you help me !
Here's The Code :


`grid.Tapped += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(GetIframeSrc(node))).AsTask().FireAndForget();
                };`

Comment: @louay can you create a sample project and send it to me? It will help me to solve your problem

Comment: @VijayNirmal give me your email and I'll send a sample

Comment: @louay Can you put it in your OneDrive and share it with me? GitHub would be even better

Comment: @VijayNirmal no problem ! I need some time and I'll replay with the link

Comment: @VijayNirmal you can download a sample from here

Comment: @VijayNirmal http://www.mediafire.com/file/3g9dgek3sdpm85b/Sample.Source1.0.0.zip

Comment: @VijayNirmal I'm waiting for your answer and The appstudio code you are already have it so it's not included

Comment: @louay I will give it a try

Comment: @louay Don't send the whole project. It is very hard to understand. Send a min repo like a page with `HtmlBlock` along with the code you tried.

Comment: @VijayNirmal the `htmlblock` in this path `Layouts\Detail\TextDetailLayout.xaml` everything you want in this xaml the html code set on this page hope this will help you

Comment: @louay I can't build your app due to some error. Can you send me min repo? Also, use code Behind instead of MVVM.

Comment: @VijayNirmal I'll send to you another one i need some time

Comment: @VijayNirmal here's a new project with only `HtmlBlock` and manual source code hope this well be better for you
http://www.mediafire.com/file/fq1zjhc711nx63d/Sample.zip

Comment: @louay It's a lot of work than I initially thought. Currently, I am busy. I will take a look at it this weekend.

Comment: @VijayNirmal no problem with that, I'm waiting for your replay!

Comment: @VijayNirmal thank you for helping me I've fix it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After 2 weeks from searching and editing codes finally I've fix it !
to resolve this you have to edit the `AppStudio.Uwp` dll file and I'll show you how:

First you havr to install the AppStudio.Uwp source code from [here](https://github.com/wasteam/waslibs/tree/master/src/AppStudio.Uwp)

after that you must remove the AppStudio.Uwp Nuget package from your project
and after that open the `AppStudio.Uwp` source code with visual studio and go to this path: `AppStudio.Uwp\Controls\HtmlBlock\Writers`

and open this file: `IFrameVideoWriter.cs`

after that replace the `DependencyObject GetControl` with this code:

```
 public override DependencyObject GetControl(HtmlFragment fragment)
    {
        var node = fragment as HtmlNode;
        MediaElement play = new MediaElement();
        if (node != null)
        {
            Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
            Windows.Storage.StorageFolder localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
            localSettings.Values["itson"] = null;
            string src = GetIframeSrc(node).ToString();
            string id = GetVideoId(src);
            string check = "";
            var grid = new Grid
            {
                HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
        };

            grid.Tapped += async (sender, e) =>
            {
                play.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
                if (localSettings.Values["itson"] == null || id != check)
                {
                        var url = await YouTube.GetVideoUriAsync(id, YouTubeQuality.Quality360P);
                        play.Source = url.Uri;
                        localSettings.Values["qv"] = "360";

                    }
                    check = id;
                    play.AreTransportControlsEnabled = true;
                    localSettings.Values["itson"] = "true";
                    play.Play();

                }
            };

            grid.PointerEntered += (sender, e) =>
            {
                Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerCursor = _handCursor;
            };
            grid.PointerExited += (sender, e) =>
            {
                Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerCursor = _arrowCursor;
            };

            AddColumn(grid);
            AddColumn(grid);
            AddColumn(grid);

            var screenShot = GetImageControl((i) => SetScreenshot(i, node));

            Grid.SetColumn(screenShot, 0);
            Grid.SetColumnSpan(screenShot, 3);
            grid.Children.Add(screenShot);

            var player = GetImageControl((i) => i.Source = GetPlayerImage());
            Grid.SetColumn(player, 1);
            grid.Children.Add(player);
            Grid.SetColumn(play, 0);
            Grid.SetColumnSpan(play, 4);
            grid.Children.Add(play);
            return grid;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

when you done build the file and import the dll file to your project and you done!
Hope this will help anyone search for it I've take two weeks to solve it by my self !